# Make Intel HD Graphics 3000 use two external displays

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have a quite old work laptop but need it to display picture on two external monitors. It has classic VGA output as well as DisplayPort output. The graphics card is Intel HD Graphics 3000.

I use external display connected to VGA port with my built-in laptop screen turned off. Yesterday I connected another external display via DisplayPort (in fact using DP => VGA converter). There was no problem with displaying picture on two external monitors. In fact I was even able to produce picture on three displays, including the built-in onev even though it's supposed to serve only two displays simultaneously!

However, after a reboot, **the display connected via DP hasn't been re-detected** and I haven't been able to wake it up from the standby mode. I've tried everything I believe - all combinations of connecting order, uninstalling built-in display (!), connecting the undetected display to VGA port and installing a dedicated driver for it and then reconnecting it via DP and so on...

Can you please suggest a way to make it display picture on two external screens at the same time (I don't really need the built-in display)?

Comment: I assume that you have gone to the "screen resolution" options in control panel to try to enable it?

Comment: @blaine - I definitely have but I haven't found it there... I have also DisplayFusion tool installed but it's doesn't help. It looks like the system doesn't send any signal to DisplayPort output.